# What's the interest of OpenID Connect Claims?

Tags: openid, openid-connect

I'm currently configuring an OpenID Connect plugin and in the "scope" field, the default values are openid profile email.

I know the openid scope is mandatory but I was wondering what is the point of the others? Why is it necessary to send user information?

And what's the claim sub for?

Answer (score 1):

'sub' is a technical identifier of the end user who signed in. After login you'll often use this to look up data in your application, such as preferences, roles or whatever.

'profile' and 'email' enable you to get hold of the name and email of the end user from the Authorization Server. This often involves sending an access token to the user info endpoint.

The key thing to understand is that in an OAuth architecture you often end up with **2 sources of user data** that you need to tie together in your applications:

- The OAuth central data
- The application specific data

My post on [User Data Management](https://authguidance.com/2017/10/02/user-data/) has some further info on managing these concerns.